# Android detect when DownloadManager has finished downloading

Tags: android

Hi i'm downloading a file and i'm wanting to fire an ACTION_VIEW Intent once its finished downloading. so does anyone know how to detect when DownloadManager has finished.

heres how i'm running DownloadManager

```
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
request.setTitle(filename);
// in order for this if to run, you must use the android 3.2 to compile your app
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
 request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
 request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);

   }

ContextWrapper c = new ContextWrapper(getBaseContext());
String filePath = c.getFilesDir().getPath();
request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(getBaseContext(), filePath, filename);

// get download service and enqueue file
DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
manager.enqueue(request);
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Downloading...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

BroadcastReceiver onComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String path = getFilesDir().getPath() +"/" + filename;
        File f = new File(path); 
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

    myIntent.setData(Uri.fromFile(f));
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }
};

registerReceiver(onComplete, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks OK for me. That example is not working? But different thing is how you fire next Intent in onReceive method. Please try use your action in 
`myIntent = new Intent(YourActionClass.class);`

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out myself i needed to set the mimeType so it knows which apps to look for